# Regex: get all matches until certain character

Tags: regex

I want to get "this" values from text before any ] character comes in.

Example:
**TEXT:**

```
start[hello:"", world:"", dsdsd:"", this:"a", wqewq:"", this:"b"], fdsfds, this:"c"
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
a, b
```

https://regex101.com/r/eZ7nN8/3

PS: I tried allday and really frustrated.

Comment: post an example here along with expected output. And also the lang you're running.

Answer (score 0):

To extract any non-empty 'this' values before the `]`, you can use

```
\bthis:"([^"]+)(?=[^\]]*])
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA4zV9/3), your value is in Group 1.

The `\bthis:"` subpattern checks if there is a `this:"` before a string of non-quotes `([^"]+)` consisting of 1 or more symbols, and `(?=[^]]*])` lookahead checks if there is a sequence of characters other than `]` before a `]`.

Comment: From the link on regex101, PCRE is chosen.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't support look-behind.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Our regexes are similar, but I am using a different style. Escaping only needs there where it is a must. Final `]` does not have to be escaped, so it is better not escaped. Quote does not have to be escaped either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use positive lookahead assertion.

```
\bthis:\"([^"]+)\"(?=[^\]]*\])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eZ7nN8/5)

Then grab the string you want from group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a pcre regex engine (php, R) or perl, you can use this kind of pattern:

```
this:"\K[^"]+(?=")|](*COMMIT)(*F)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ0sE8/1)

`\K` and the lookahead `(?=")` are used here to avoid the creation of a capture group. `\K` removes all on the left from the whole match. So the whole match contains only the content between quotes.

The backtracking control verb `(*COMMIT)` forces the whole match to fail if the pattern fails later. Since `(*F)` makes the pattern fail, the research is stopped when the `]` is reached.

Comment: BTW, you do not even need a look-ahead: `this:"\K[^"]+|](*COMMIT)(*F)` is enough. I do not get your explanation of `\K and the lookahead (?=") are used here to avoid the creation of a capture group.` I do not see any capturing group here. Well, in plain terms, `](*COMMIT)(*F)` here acts just as a look-ahead - is there any benefit of using it rather than a lookahead?

Comment: @stribizhev: the lookahead is only here to be more descriptive (as an aside it may prevent to match an unbalanced quote at the end of the string). About the construct `](*COMMIT)(*F)`, the main interest is that you avoid to test the string for each match until the `]`.

Comment: @stribizhev: to be more performant, the pattern can be written like this: `~this:"\K([^"]*(?=")|](*COMMIT)(*F)~S`, the `S` modifier improve the search when the branches of an alternation that start with a literal. Unfortunately regex101 doesn't support this modifier.

Comment: But this would fail if the input is `start[hello:"", world:"", dsdsd:"", this:"a", wqewq:"", this:"b"], fdsfds, this:"c" start[hello:"", world:"", dsdsd:"", this:"a", wqewq:"", this:"b"]` .. And also op is using a lang which won't support lookbehind. So `\K` or `COMMIT` must not be supported as well.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: indeed, but without more informations, it is actually the desired behaviour. The OP uses regex101 in PCRE mode, and didn't add a language tag, so it isn't my problem.